# Average value of <List> C#

Tags: c#, list, button, stopwatch

I need code which writes average value from `<List>` to `textBox1`. Clicking `button1` 2 times `textBox1`should give me average value of ElapsedMilliseconds from `rotorSpeed`.

```
    Stopwatch rotorSpeed = new Stopwatch();
    List<double> list = new List<double>();
    double av;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        do
        {
            if (rotorSpeed.IsRunning)
            {
                rotorSpeed.Stop();
                list.Add(rotorSpeed.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                rotorSpeed.Reset();
                rotorSpeed.Start();
            }
        } while (i == 2);

        av = list.Average();
        textBox1.Text = av.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question lack the question...

Comment: while (i >= 2) would never be true here, what are you trying to do?

Comment: @sachin Yea i == 2 sorry

Comment: @rltcounter221 even i==2 won't ever be true, you're never incrementing the counter in the loop.

Comment: @sachin thats why i need your help. What I want is for 2 button clicks I get average value of milliseconds to textbox

Comment: Is this what you mean: "`At the first button click, I want to start measuring the rotor speed, sampling the speed several times per second. At the second button click, I want to stop measuring the rotor speed, and display in the UI the average rotor speed over the interval when the rotor speed was being measured.`? (And furthermore, the use of `Stopwatch` for the rotor speed is merely for emulation purposes.)

Comment: @MatthewWatson So I want to measure rotor speed twice so I can get average value because rotor is faster in the first revolution then in the second. Brief explanation: "At the first button click, I want stopwatch start and then and the second click I want to put sw.ElapsedMilliseconds to list. Now on the third click I want stopwatch to reset and then immediately start and save that value to list. So there are now 2 values in the list."

Comment: You probably need a static variable `i`. At least it's called static for C and C++, dunno about C#.

Answer (score -1):

You should put the initialization of i outside of the event

```
Stopwatch rotorSpeed = new Stopwatch();
List<double> list = new List<double>();
double av;
int i = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    i++;
    if (i == 2)
    {
        if (rotorSpeed.IsRunning)
        {
            rotorSpeed.Stop();
            list.Add(rotorSpeed.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            rotorSpeed.Reset();
            rotorSpeed.Start();
        }
        i=0;
    } 

    av = list.Average();
    textBox1.Text = av.ToString();
}
```

}

Comment: That will still hang indefinitely. i never gets to 2 so the loop keeps on going

Comment: It sets i=0... 
Of course, it could be changed to an if :-)